# Keyboard modes like modes in vim

Tags: macos, vim

I'd like to be able to hit `capslock` and have many keyboard mappings change. `j` would be mapped to `downarrow`, `k` to `uparrow` etc. like the basics of command mode in vim.

Then I'd be able to navigate a bit "vim-like" in all apps.

Anybody know a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can accomplish what you're describing, but you'll need both Seil and Karabiner.  Karabiner alone can't remap the <kbd>caps lock</kbd> key

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) keyboard customizer with Vim key binding.

[image]